# Creating a second Personal Folder on MS Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst

I am using MS Outlook 2002 (no choice mandated by company). I got a message that my personal folder was too big (it really was). I need to keep past emails for reference purposes.

I would like to split the personal folder along years and link in the folder with past years into Outlook as well as the standard Personal Folder for the current year.

I have created a copy of the Personal Folder (pst) with a different name (PersonalFolder08.pst) and would like to link it into Outlook, but can't seem to find the right menu options.

Is it possible to link more than one pst file into Outlook?
If so how?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "linking"? Integrate into the folder structure of the standard pst?

Comment: @splattne: I mean have it visible in the Folder List on Outlook

Comment: click on file open and browse to the folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Outlook 2007 there's an option in Account Settings to add Data files or you could reach it through File --> Data File Management. Here you can add your new .pst and then start dragging emails between the two folders.

Though your best bet would probably to "archive" you large .pst and then make sure you link to those. It's less hacky and Outlook does the work for you

Note: I'm not sure where to find you File Management in 2002...